# Taking back Up of Microsoft Access Database in c# .Net Windows App

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, oledb

I am developing one c# .NET application.

I am using database of Microsoft Access(OLEDB).

I want to take back up of database time to time (Programatically).

(Or As i can create .bak file in sqlserver2008 r2)

What should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Access database is usually a single file.
To do a programmatic backup you can simply use a

```
File.Copy(sourceDbName, destDbName, true);
```

Of course you can add a simple routine that takes your input database, zip and store it, in your backup directory, optionally passing a password, like this:

```
using Ionic.Zip;
......

private void BackupToZip(string sourceDBName, string destZipFile, string password)
{
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(destZipFile))
    {
        if (bkpPass.Length > 0) zip.Password = password;
        ZipEntry e = zip.UpdateFile(sourceDbName, string.Empty);
        e.Comment = "Working copy stored in date: " + DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
        zip.Comment = "This zip archive has been created by ......";
        zip.Save();
    }
}
```

this snippet of code requires the [DotNetZip Library](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)